# python Split list dynamically

Tags: python

I am trying to generate links based on number of elements from a list. I have a column which contains lots of shipping ids.
I copied this column to a list *id_list*. 
Next I created a string *str2* from this list and joined it with 2 other strings to create a link. and write it to a file.

Now i want to split the list to smaller lists with each having 400 elements. And to generate separate link for each sub-list. But i am not able to split this list. How to do this?

NOTE: The number of elements in id_list change daily so i need to dynamically generate links on the basis of number of elements.

My Code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Unicommerce.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
temp_list = []
id_list = []
cur.execute("""Select shipment from unicom;""")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    temp_list.append(row)

for sublist in temp_list:
    for element in sublist:
        id_list.append(element)

str1 = "abc.com/oms/shipment/show/"
str2 = '-'.join([str(num) for num in id_list])
str3 = "?legacy=1"
link_str = str1 + str2 + str3
file = open("Shipment.txt","wb")
file.writelines(link_str)
file.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This list comprehension using a modified version of your code will work:

```
str1 = "abc.com/oms/shipment/show/"
str3 = "?legacy=1"
n=400
link_strings = [str1 + '-'.join([str(num) for num in id_list[i:i+n]]) + str3 for i in xrange(0, len(id_list), n)]
```

Change the value of n to change the chunk size.

Here is a condensed example using a smaller chunking size:

```
id_list=range(10)

id_list
Out[2]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

str1 = "abc.com/oms/shipment/show/"
str3 = "?legacy=1"
n=4
link_strings = [str1 + '-'.join([str(num) for num in id_list[i:i+n]]) + str3 for i in xrange(0, len(id_list), n)]


link_strings
Out[4]: 
['abc.com/oms/shipment/show/0-1-2-3?legacy=1',
 'abc.com/oms/shipment/show/4-5-6-7?legacy=1',
 'abc.com/oms/shipment/show/8-9?legacy=1']
```

Comment: This can easily lead to out of bound error in `id_list[i:i+n]`.

Comment: @KassymDorsel could you provide an example where it goes out of bounds?  This list comprehension works fine for id_list of varying sizes.

Comment: @KassymDorsel: `id_list[i:i+n]` can't generate an IndexError.  Even `[1,2,3][200:400]` simply returns the empty list.

Comment: Sorry, did my research, you guys are right. Had not realized this about Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> map(None, *[iter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])]*3)
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, None)]
```

You may replace the list for your **id_list** and number **3** for **400**.